# Java SSL Handshake Issue

Tags: java, ssl, applet, rsa

I am further toward getting this SSL connection working but if someone could tell me why my applet is triggering a 'sslv3 alert certificate unknown" error that would be great.  I found this error by running "openssl s_server" and (trying) to connect to it using my Java client.  I will include the source for the program.  I heard it could be the lack of a trust store but I created one and it didn't help.

```
public class first extends JApplet  {

    PrintWriter toServer = null;
    BufferedReader fromServer = null;

    public void init() {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "javakeys");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "javakeys");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.ts"); 
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "javakeys"); 

try {

        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("localhost", 4000);

        toServer = new PrintWriter(sslsocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        toServer.println("Flystar\n\r");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream());
        fromServer = new BufferedReader(isr, 1);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, fromServer );


    } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
    }

//      toServer.println("Flystar".getBytes());

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor( Color.red );
        g.drawString("Welcome to Java!!", 50, 60 );
    }


}
```

Thanks,
-Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sslv3 alert certificate unknown" means that the server's certificate is in a format that your Java client doesn't understand.

Comment: Is the problem with the server side (.key) or the Java client public certificate?

Comment: Do I need to create a signed jar?

Comment: @user1220811 Calm down! Your problem is in the *server's certificate,* as I already said, i.e. at the other end: not in your code, your JAR, your certificate, your key, ...

Comment: I can connect fine to my server using "openssl s_client" everything seems to be fine on that end

Comment: @user1220811 So the openSSL client understands the server certificate. However Java doesn't. So everything isn't 'fine on that end' unless you are prepared not to use Java clients.